# How to mix and animate a lot of shaders

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

So I have 12 shaders of rather complex materials. I need to be able to smoothly mix between these shaders and be able to animate this mix.

At the moment I have this setup (12 shaders into a mix shader tree):[image]

I can animate the factors of this Mix Shader tree to get the smooth changes I need but this is a lot of work to change between materials as I have to keyframe a lot of factors. Is there a way to have a Switch Shader node? Or to create one?

Thanks

Comment: What about using drivers?

Comment: Hi :). Do you only want to switch between shaders, or blend between them gradually?

Comment: You can add a value node which takes numbers 1-12 and calculate from these the settings of your mix nodes?

Comment: Hi, I want to smoothly "switch" between them. So yeah blend :). I do not know what drivers are, I will check this.

Comment: The calculate way is not super flexible I think? As it does not let me choose what materials I want to blend?

Comment: I am now trying this which is already a lot more usable: https://imgur.com/JqMpRX9 and https://imgur.com/fogVAW1